# Does tensorflow cache data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, constants

In the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Session():
    input_features = tf.constant(np.reshape([2, 1, 1, 2], (1, 4)).astype(np.float32))
    print(input_features)
    weights = tf.constant(np.random.randn(4, 2).astype(np.float32))
    output = tf.matmul(input_features, weights)
    print("Input:")
    print(input_features.eval())
    print("Weights:")
    print(weights.eval())
    print("Output:")
    print(output.eval())
```

When it calls `print(weights.eval())` weights will be calculated. When it calls `output.eval()`, will weights be calculated again, or it will be using the cached values from previous call?

Answer (score 0):

The `weights` is a **constant tensor**, which gets a value upon running this line:

```
weights = tf.constant(np.random.randn(4, 2).astype(np.float32))
```

... and this value is actually stored in the graph and never changes, just like `input_features`. You can evaluate `weights` or any dependent op and always get the same result. Of course, Tensorflow stores the values of *all* constants and variables within a session, you can call it cache if you'd like.

The only point of randomness here is the value itself: `np.random.randn(4, 2)`. This array will be different each time you run the script (but will be the same within a script, as described above).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful!

Comment: Hi @user9524761 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.